# Why signed char can hold bigger values than 127?

Tags: c++, char

```
int main()
{
    char MCU = 0b00000000;
    char al_av = 0b10100000;

    // Before bit operation
    cout << "MCU = " << int(MCU) << endl;

    MCU = MCU | al_av;

    // After the bit operation
    cout << "MCU = " << int(MCU) << endl;   // Expected 160, got -96

    char temp = 160;

    cout << temp;   // got the a with apostrophe

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output of `char temp` to be a negative number (or a warning / error) because 160 exceeds the [-127,127] interval, but instead, the result was the one in the ASCII table (*a with apostrophe*)

On [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types):

> char - type for character representation which can be most efficiently processed on the target system (*has the same representation and alignment as either signed char or unsigned char, but is always a distinct type*)

I don't understand what is written in italic (also I'm not sure it helps a lot for this question). Is there any implicit conversion ?

Comment: Note that `char` is not guaranteed to be signed. From the link you posted: *"The signedness of char depends on the compiler and the target platform: the defaults for ARM and PowerPC are typically unsigned, the defaults for x86 and x64 are typically signed."*

Comment: the part in italic means that `char` is either signed or unsigned, but in any case `char`, `unsigend char` and `signed char` are 3 (!) different types. Not really related to your question i think

Comment: Please provide the compiler used, any compiler options you've specified, and the platform you're running this on. Those are relevant to what's happening.

Comment: `231` in your code is `integer literal` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) which is _implicitly cast_ (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to your 'char' type

Comment: @mvidelgauz answers should go to answers

Comment: @DeducibleSteak I'm running CodeBlocks on a 64 bit windows 10 platform. The compiler i use is  `GCC/G++ compiler and GDB debugger from TDM-GCC (version 5.1.0, 32 bit, SJLJ)` (MinGw). As settings, i only have the `C++14 ISO standard` checked!

Comment: I had misread "// Expected 160, got -96" the other way around, my line of inquiry was headed in the wrong direction. @YSC has your answer.

Comment: `MCU` should be declared `unsigned char MCU;`. Otherwise if you have `int foo = int(MCU);`, `MCU` will be sign extended to `0xffffffa0` which is `-96`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why signed char can hold bigger values than 127?

It cannot.

```
char x = 231;
```

here, there is an (implicit) integer conversion: 231 is a *prvalue* of type `int` and takes value `-25` before it is converted to `char` (which is signed on your system). You can ask your compiler to warn you about it with `-Wconstant-conversion`.

---

> char - type for character representation which can be most efficiently processed on the target system (*has the same representation and alignment as either signed char or unsigned char, but is always a distinct type*)
>
> I don't understand what is written in italic

This isn't related to what the type can hold, it only ensures that the three types `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` have common properties.

Comment: ok so does it means that from this http://www.asciitable.com/ , on a `signed char` variable, the negative values are taken like this : `-1 = 128, -2 = 129, etc.`?

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu No. It will depend on how your value will be interpreted by whatever lib matching integer value and characters. If you use `std::cout` to print for instance, it will depend on the specific implementation of your run-time on your environment.

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu • on my system, -1 = 255, -2 = 254, etc.

Answer (score 3):

From C++14 `char`, if `signed`, must be a 2's complement type. That means that it has the range of *at least* -128 to +127. It's important to know that the range *could* be larger than this so it's incorrect to assume that a number greater than 127 cannot be stored in a `char` if `signed`. Use

```
std::numeric_limits<char>::max()
```

to get the real upper limit on your platform.

If you do assign a value larger than this to a `char` and `char` is `signed` then the behaviour of your code is implementation defined. Typically that means *wrap-around* to a negative which is practically universal behaviour for a signed `char` type.

Note also that ASCII is a 7 bit encoding, so it's wrong to say that any character outside the range 0 - 127 is ASCII. Note also that ASCII is not the only encoding supported by C++. There are others.

Finally, the distinct types: Even if `char` is `signed`, it is a different type from `signed char`. This means that the code

```
int main() {
    char c;
    signed char d;
    std::swap(c, d);
}
```

will always result in a compile error.

Comment: What change in the C++14 standard requires signed `char` to be 2's complement?

Comment: I thought C++20 required 2s complement.  Prior to that, it could be 1s or 2s.  (Other encodings were not accommodated.)

Comment: @Eljay: C++20 requires 2's complement for all signed integral types. C++14 requires it for signed char and char if signed.

Comment: [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) say that prior to C++20, signed char types could be 1s, and also noted that all known C++ compilers used 2s complement (prior to C++20, but (probably) C++11 and after).  Not that CppReference is authoritative; they do sometimes make mistakes (albeit rarely).

Answer (score -2):

```
char temp = 160;
```

It is actually negative. The point is cout supports non-ASCII characters, so it interprets it as non-negative. cout is probably casting it to unsigned char (or any unsigned integral type) before using it.

If you use printf and tell it to interpret it as an integer you will see that it is a negative value.

```
printf("%d\n", temp); // prints -96
```

Comment: It works only because `printf` being a variadic function sees its arguments converted to `int`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions

Comment: @YSC it works because char is signed type and it holds negative value. Thats what i want to show.